# First variable is overwrited by the second variable in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

For example ,
I have two shell script file name `main.sh` and `child.sh` and one ini file name `param.ini`.

In main.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
./usr/child.sh
echo $param // show Jame
var=${param}How are you
echo $var // output show only How are you and  Jame is overwrited.The output should Jame How are you
```

In child.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
./usr/param.ini

param=$name
echo $param // show Jame
```

In param.ini

```
 name=Jame
```

After execute main.sh the output show How are you and Jame is missing.
Jame is overwrited.
What I want is **Jame How are you**

Comment: You know `//` is  not a shell comment, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be ok with replace method of shell.
Set a keyword in value of ini file. For example

```
key1 = valueA //'A' will be used as a key word.
```

In shell, implement replace method as follows:

```
var = "${param/A/HowAreYou}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `.` for sourcing, use the command `source`. It will work.

**OR**

source it like `. param.ini` (note the space between `.` and `param.ini`)

```
sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ cat main.sh 
#!/bin/bash
source child.sh
echo "$param"
var="${param}, How are you"
echo "$var"

sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ cat child.sh 
#!/bin/bash
source param.ini
param=$name
echo $param

sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ cat param.ini 
name=Jame

sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ bash main.sh 
Jame
Jame
Jame, How are you
```

Comment: I change . to source but is still not ok.But if i use like this var="How are you"${param} // output show How are you Jame. until not ok like var="${parm}How are you" // output show only how are you.

Comment: `${parm}` - there is a spelling mistake. Also FYI, in `bash`, `#` is for commenting and not `//`

Comment: sorry for spelling mistake.I use var="${param},How are you" and i use # is for commenting.Further more test in child.sh have the same case.In child.sh param="$name how are you" // output also how are you and jame is missing but echo $name // output show jame

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 var="${param}How are you"
```

instead of

```
var=${param}How are you
```